# Different lighting behavior on different machines

Tags: c++, opengl

I recently tried to make an .obj mesh loader in C++ with OpenGL and I am confronted to a strange problem.

I have a `std::vector<Vector3f>` that reprensents the coords of the vertices of the faces, and another one that represents its normals. In my `Vector3f`, there is a `std::array<float,3>` so I can preserve contiguity between elements.

```
// Vertex Pointer to triangle array
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vector3f), &(_triangles[0].data[0]));

// Normal pointer to normal array
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(Vector3f),&(_normals[0].data[0]));
```

When I compile the program on my school computers, it gives the good results, but when I compile it on my desktop computer, the lighting is strange, it's like all the faces are reflecting light in the camera, and so they appear all white.

Do you guys have any idea of what could be my problem ?

EDIT :

My computer is under ArchLinux, my window manager is Awesome, and this is written on a sticker on my pc

```
Intel Core i7-3632QM 2.2GHz with Turbo Boost up to 3.2GHz.
NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M
```

I don't know much about my school computers, but I think they are on Ubuntu.

Comment: your desktop environment (both OS and physical)?

Comment: You're right, this could be usefull... I should have thought of it. I added it in my post !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it.

Of course, with such a little information, it would be difficult for anyone esle to find the answer.

This was based on sources given by school, and at a certain point, the shininess of the mesh was defined that way

```
glMaterialf (GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 250);
```

However, in the [Open GL documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glMaterial.xml), it specified that

> Only values in the range [0, 128] are accepted.

So I guess the different version of OpenGL reacted differently to this mistake :

- my school's version of OpenGL probably decided to clamp the value of the shininess in [0,128]
- my computer's version probably made saturated the shininess, which is why I had so bright results.

However, thank you very much for your help, and for taking time to read this post.

Comment: The way I understand the spec, calling this with a value larger than 128 should generate a `GL_INVALID_VALUE`, and leave the current value unchanged. The default value is 0.0. So your home computer most likely handled this correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the precision, you're probably right !